# How to do authentication using JWT in my project?

Tags: authentication, jwt, authorization, mern

I have implemented registration, login and logout functionality using JWT in my MERN project, but the problem is whoever logging is accessing the same database. Every user should have access to his/her database only. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When validating a JWT you must do **both** authentication and authorisation. First you check that the JWT has a valid signature, then you can read (and trust) information from the JWT.

The JWT can contain anything you like. It typically contains a `sub` that is an ID of the subject (the user), and you can use that to choose what DB to redirect the incoming request to. You can also put information about what DB a specific user should have access to directly in the JWT, perhaps in the `scopes` property.

So, authorisation is done in code, based on the information in the (valid) JWT. Either you code it yourself, or you find some library that can help you. It's normally just a couple of lines of code though.

Comment: What is role-based and can it be used here?

Comment: @VP1996 - You can put anything in your JWT, scopes with access rights, or roles that latter on provides you with some access. As long as you remember that it's sent in every request and for that reason should not be too large, you can put more or less of the clients access right in your JWT. It's a balance. For very common operations, it's handy if the JWT is enough to determine if the user should have access or not. For more rare operations, it's OK to use the `sub` in the JWT to look up more specific access rights.